# What happened to our chat?

Tags: discussion, site-promotion, chat

I'm new to meta, so..

Let's get straight to this, what happen to our chat, how can it so awful quiet? When I go down there, and ask for anyone, then @Dom replied:

> Yep usually only a short burst of chatter then it gets silent. We
>   should try to get more people in here and then it will probably be
>   more active. I know I'm up for using the chat more, but I find it hard
>   to start a conversation with no one in here.

How can we make our chat more noisy, so everyone can discuss and talk about music there? Without that, it feels that this community just came up with no interaction at all. All's just like about Q & A without relation (of friendship/other, seriously) that anyone interact into.

So, any idea or suggestion about chat that can make it more noisy?

---

@DrMayhem said:

### Simple Solution - use it. Chat. Every day. Encourage others

Comment: Maybe we need to get a core group of users to commit to hanging out in chat regularly -- similar to how sites enter Beta in the first place...

Comment: Animated gifs are the best way to make a chatroom noisy. :P Also what NReilingh said.

Comment: I do not see the point of chat in any of the SE sites. These sites feel very useful to me as an asynchronous tool, but much less useful to me as a place to chat. I doubt I'm typical but that's why you won't find me in the chat room

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I typically hang out in 14 chats, and the only really active ones are the DMZ (for security folks), the Teacher's Lounge (for all SE mods) and the Comms Room.

All others have varying levels of activity, and most beta chat sites I visit need a regular ping to avoid being frozen for inactivity.

Some subjects lend themselves well to chat - but all need a certain minimum number of users to become self sustaining.

I would expect Music to have one of the best uses for chat - as we have so much that is subjective, discussion-worthy or otherwise slightly outside SE requirements for Questions and Answers.

**Simple Solution** - use it. Chat. Every day. Encourage others.

Answer (score 8):

Er- what chat? where's the link?

I can see it now I've looked around (next to the subject title in the StackExchange dropdown) but until now I didn't even know there is a chat.

Maybe making the link more prominant would help.

Comment: http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/440/musical-practice-and-performance It is the chat link in the drop down menu

Comment: Yea - I found it - I just think it's not all that obvious or "in the line of sight", particularly if you've only joined one SE community so don't need to look at that menu so much.

Comment: The chat is also visible in the right column in the Meta main page, although it is not glaring at you. I noticed it through that square at least...

Comment: Agreed. I believe they changed to location of the chat link - it used be right up there - now it seems harder to find.

Answer (score 3):

Even if you find nobody there, *say hello!* Maybe even drop a link to your (current) favorite song.

Remember SE operate globally, across *all* timezones, and everybody keeps crazy hours anyway. So if everybody's missing each other by an hour and a hemisphere, and nobody leaves breadcrumbs, it looks even deader than it is. :)

Answer (score 2):

The chat here is very quiet indeed, and it should not be. The history site used to have very active chat and we sorted out and fought about everything that we couldn't do on the main site. We also got to know each other personally - discussed our work in detail, etc.

One the big things missing on all the SE sites is the ability for anyone to move their discussion with someone to chat from the comments section.

Right now there seems to be some arbitrary point, at which you get prompted to go chat, or the mod moves you to chat, which often has negative consequences, removing important points from body of a question or answer and moving it all to chat.